# How can I use both OR & AND conditions in django filters?

Tags: django, django-views

In my code i have some filter conditions where i have to use OR condition in between some AND conditions in django filter.Here,is my code

```
  def get_initial_queryset(self):
     filterCondition={'iType':1}
     if status:
         statusCondition={'iApprovedStatus': status}
         filtercondition.update(statusCondition)
     .......
     EIDlist=[1,2,5,7]
     EIDcondition={'EID__in':EIDlist]
     TIDlist=[5,8,9,10]
     TIDcondition={'TID__in':TIDlist]
     filtercondition.update(EIDcondition)
     filtercondition.update(TIDcondition)
     executeQuery = ENTITY_TEMPLATES.objects.filter(**filterCondition).order_by('-dtCreatedOn')
```

Here,i need to apply OR condition between EIDlist and TIDlist. But, in filtercondition it will take as AND and i'm getting wrong resultset.How can i do this query?
Any suggestions?
-TIA

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Q` objects to do that kind of logic. Refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Here is a simple example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

ENTITY_TEMPLATES.objects.filter(
    Q(EID__in=EIDlist) | Q(TID__in=TIDlist),  # 1
    iType=1,  # 2
    iApprovedStatus=status  # 3
)
```

You end up with this logic: (1) AND 2 AND 3, where (1) contains an OR. Note that `,` implies AND.

Comment: That works normally. But, in my case i need in dictionary format(filtercondition)

Comment: You cannot easily put that into a dictionary because the `Q` conditions won't have names/keys. Maybe you can try one of the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131563/django-filter-with-or-condition-using-dict-argument